# How can I use Ruby to check if a domain exists?

Tags: ruby, validation, dns, registrar

Something along the lines of:

```
def domain_exists?(domain)
  # perform check
  # return true|false
end

puts "valid!" if domain_exists?("example.com")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check whether a domain is registered or not, then you need to perform a Whois query.
http://www.ruby-whois.org/

Answer (score 8):

```
require 'socket'

def domain_exists?(domain)
  begin
    Socket.gethostbyname(domain)
  rescue SocketError
    return false
  end

  true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ruby-whois` is pretty easy:

Install gem and require.

```rb
a = Whois.whois("google.com")

a.available?
=> false
```

There is also a CLI bundled if you install it via ruby gems: `ruby-whois`

web page at: [ruby-whois.org](http://www.ruby-whois.org/)

Comment: Simon Carletti, the first in replying is your man for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could shell out to nslookup like this:

```
`nslookup #{domain}`
```

and parse the results as text with regexes etc.

Or you can use the [Socket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M004531) class, specifically Socket.getaddrinfo. See previous [StackOverflow answer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M004531) on this very question.